# Dymola converting output files to sdf - doesn't work for large files?

Tags: dymola, sdf

After simulation is finished Dymola runs dsres2sdf.exe to convert the results to sdf-format (if that option is enabled in the simulation setup output tab).

Usually this runs smoothly but sometimes it generates a sdf file that is very small (800 Byte) and empty.
Starting the dsres2sdf.exe manually from command line generates the same empty file.

I suspect that happens if the *.mat-File is very large (>1 GB)

Anybody has any clue how to get a proper sdf-File?

Comment: just a side comment: If you don't necessarily want your files to be that big,  Variable Selections could be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SDF Editor and the SDF libraries for [Python](https://github.com/ScientificDataFormat/SDF-Python) and [MATLAB](https://github.com/ScientificDataFormat/SDF-MATLAB) can read Dymola result files (*.mat) transparently (as if they were SDFs) and allow you to save them as *.sdf.

For example with Python:

```py
import sdf

# load the Dymola result file
data = sdf.load('DoublePendulum.mat')

# re-save as SDF
sdf.save('DoublePendulum.sdf', data)
```